# I cannot find file spawn.h in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I install cygwin 1.7.10 on windows 7.
I want to install gearmand-0.28,when during the make,it can't find spawn.h.
The error is:

```
./libtest/cmdline.h:24:19: fatal error: spawn.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:4157: recipe for target `libtest/libtest_libtest_la-binaries.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [libtest/libtest_libtest_la-binaries.lo] Error 1
make[1]: 离开目录“/home/power/gearmand-0.28”
Makefile:2072: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Which package I need install?

Comment: It has been reported upstream btw https://bugs.launchpad.net/gearmand/+bug/1048945

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's an issue with some versions of gearman with Cygwin. I finally managed to install gearmand, but an old version: 0.14. (see https://launchpad.net/gearmand/+download )

My environment: Cygwin 1.7.13-1, Windows 7 64-bit.

Don't forget to install boost, gcc, make, libuuid1-devel and libiconv. You can download & install them with Cygwin (setup.exe)